# delete data from android firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a **social media** application with firebase in android studio, now my application is finished, it works smoothly, but there is a problem, there is a delete button on the shared post, when this button is clicked, I want it to delete only that selected picture.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Did you try calling `removeValue` on a `DatabaseReference` to that data as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking about firebase database you can do something like

```
// Reference to the node you want to delete
DatabaseReference postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts").child(postId);

// Delete the node
postRef.removeValue();
```

in case you are talking about firebase storage you can do something like

```
// Reference to the image you want to delete
StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child("images/myimage.jpg");

// Delete the image
imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted successfully
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

you must include the dependency in build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
```

sorry i didn't had enough reputation here to comment and ask so directly posting an answer